# How to select % from table mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

i have a table, lets say it has 100 rows.

```
| id   | table 1 |
| 1    | blaabla |
| 2    | blaabla |
..
| 100  | blaabla |
```

how do i select 10 percent of the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) window function with `COUNT` for percent calculation. Window functions are supported in MariaDB as of version 10.2.

```sql
SELECT 
     sub.id
      , sub.col1
      , sub.col2
      , sub.col3
FROM
  (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) / 
             COUNT(*) OVER() AS rn_pct
      , id
      , col1
      , col2
      , col3
   FROM myTable) sub
WHERE sub.rn_pct <= 0.1
```

The blank `OVER()` means across all rows. For last 10%, replace default `ASC` for `DESC`. Also, you can add `PARTITION BY` to both window function inside `OVER()` to add grouping columns for 10% in *each* grouping slice!

Comment: (Don't try this on a large table -- the performance won't be pretty.)  MySQL 8.0 can also do such.